# Running a command as a specific user on an ec2 using ssm

Tags: amazon-web-services, linux, aws-cli

### Background

I want to automatically configure an EC2 via a build, using the aws cli and ssm.

The (manual) setup for the container looks something like this:

- Create an EC2
- Run a shell script as root
- Run a shell script as a specific user

### Question

Is it possible to run a command on an ec2 utilising a tool such as `aws ssm send-command` specifying the linux user which will execute the command?

Assuming the command is a shell script, would specifying the user inside the script do the same job? e.g using `sudo su my_user`

Comment: Welcome to DevOps.SE.  Running `sudo` when you're already `root` is superfluous.  Just `su` and then do stuff as that user.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420291/2002471

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't find anything on AWS or boto3 docs that allows for that, but I was able to execute as a different user using the `runuser` command. In theory, you could do the same thing with a combination of `sudo` and `su` commands, but this one is pretty simpler.

For that, you can do as follows:

```
runuser -l  userNameHere -c '/path/to/command arg1 arg2'
```

Since send-command executes as root, you don't have any issues.

**Note:** I thought that send-command uses in some way a session managed by the *SSM Session Manager*, but I was wrong. I spent a good time configuring *SSM Session Manager* preferences and tagging IAM resources according to [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-preferences-run-as.html) and [this one](https://reinvent2019.aws-management.tools/mgt406/en/optional/step5.html), but send-command always execute as root as far I saw.

Sources:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/runuser.1.html
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/

Comment: Thank you! This also helped me when trying to execute a script via _AWS Systems Manager - Run Command_, since `su - username` wasn't allowing me to switch the user from `root`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, you saved my day. Documentation is so weak. And running command after or with `sudo su - username` did not work at all, even if I send it in same command separated with `;` or as list of command.